# Gravity Forms Payments with multiple conditions

Tags: php, paypal, authorize.net, gravity-forms-plugin, donations

I have a donation form with options to have a user pay with credit card (auth.net) or with PayPal. I also have an option to have the user set up recurring donations.

I need to condition checks to send the payment to Auth.net when the credit card option is selected as well as when the credit card and recurring donation is checked (same for paypal).

Unfortunately, payment processing conditionals only offer one option...so I'm a bit stuck at this point. Any extensions or suggestions to get this to work? Client has requested that they accept both Auth.net and Paypal (even though yes, paypal does accept credit cards...they still want this).

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to have all of your conditions in one field (I normally use a radio button field) so that you can then use this field in your conditional logic for both your credit card field and your payment processing feeds.

Check out this [example using PayPal and Stripe](https://gravityplus.pro/how-to/setup-multiple-payment-options-on-one-gravity-form/) — it works the same for any payment processor (there's also an example form there that you can import into your site to see how it works directly in the form editor).

Comment: @ian does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and thought it was a showstopper but this is what I did:

I needed 4 feeds:
Pay via CC
Pay via CC Recurring
Pay via PayPal
Pay via PayPal Recurring

BUT, I had a checkbox handling recurring (Yes), and radio buttons handling the payment type (CC/PayPal) and did NOT want to unify them.

So, I assigned my recurring a value of "1"
I assigned my "Pay with CC" a value of "3" and PayPal at "0"

I created a new Number field and labeled it "PayPal Conditional Logic"
I then enabled calculation to add "recurring+payment type".

So, now the feeds:
Send to PayPal if "PayPal Conditional Logic" is 0
Send to PayPal as Subscription if "PayPal Conditional Logic" is 1
Pay with CC if "PayPal Conditional Logic" is 3
Pay with CC as Subscription if "PayPal Conditional Logic" is 4

worked for me :)